# combining similar data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have following data :

```
 date     | source              | session | device
 5/1/2016 | facebook.com/social | 5       | mobile
 5/1/2016 | facebook.com/post   | 50      | desktop
 5/1/2016 | facebook.com/commun | 25      | mobile
 5/1/2016 | pintrest.com/social | 15      | mobile
 5/1/2016 | pintrest.com/commun | 25      | mobile
```

I need data like:

```
 date     | source              | session | device
 5/1/2016 | facebook            | 30      | mobile
 5/1/2016 | facebook            | 50      | desktop
 5/1/2016 | pintrest            | 40      | mobile
```

I am using MySQL database

Comment: what have you done to fullfill your needs?

Comment: What have you already tried? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Your data doesn't match up.  The source has `50 | desktop` as the only desktop row, but your expected results have `65 | desktop` in it.  Also, you don't articulate any rules that you want to follow; should `source` be shortened to everything before the first `.`?  Or can some of the data have `www.facebook.com`?  Then, I'm assuming that you want to group by `data, shortened_source, device`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use the first occurrence of the dot as your shortened URL ('.'), then the following will work for you.

```
select
  date
  , LEFT(source, LOCATE('.', source) - 1) as 'short_source'
  , sum(sessions) as  'sessions'
  , device
from date
group by 
  date
  , LEFT(source, LOCATE('.', source) - 1)
  , device
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a69c5/3)

Ok, so to cater for if the table contains an invalid URL (in this case a url without a DOT):

```
select
  date
  , COALESCE(LEFT(source, LOCATE('.', source) - 1), 'invalid_url') as 'short_source'
  , sum(sessions) as  'sessions'
  , device
from date
group by 
  date
  , LEFT(source, LOCATE('.', source) - 1)
  , device
```

Comment: Also assumes that there is *always* at least one `.` in the string.

Comment: Absolutely - however, given the lack of clarity in the question, is the best to be going on with, i think...